# Is it against the rules to mark question as favourite in another account owned by same person?

Tags: discussion, accounts, bookmarks, rules

If someone owns multiple Stack Overflow accounts, is it against the rules to mark a question as favourite asked by another account? Marking question as favourite is for tracking purposes. Please note that no mutual voting will be involved.

Comment: @Glorfindel Yes, but it's about using multiple accounts in general which is not allowed in the first place, which will probably make this question duplicate on almost any multiple accounts related question

Comment: @AlonEitan on the contrary, it *is* allowed. [Even Shog uses them for testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/295232), and there are situations where it's 'convenient' (and allowed) to be able to ask a question 'anonymously' with a new account.

Comment: @Glorfindel That's strange, because I remember I saw answers/comments saying that it's not allowed, but if Shog uses them, then who am i to pass judgement (Retracted my vote)

Comment: @AlonEitan you were probably thinking about not being allowed to create a secondary account to circumvent an account ban.

Comment: @Gimby Yes. That, or to create a secondary account just to improve your main account reputation by upvoting your own questions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general rule about having multiple accounts is as follows:

> Don't do with two accounts what you can't do with only one.

If you ask a question, can you favourite it? Yes, you can. But you *can't* favourite your own question twice, so use only one account to favourite the question and you'll be fine.

Note that marking something as a favorite actually *is* a kind of vote: see the definition of the [SEDE Votes table](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types), VoteTypeId = 5.

Comment: If it is some kind of vote, isn't that fraud even if I favourite the question only once?

Comment: No, because the system lets you favourite *your own* question. It doesn't do that with upvotes.

Comment: Thanks for the reassuring reply. One question. I don't see the logic for the system to allow a person to favourite his own question. Every question asked is automatically tracked, so favouriting the question is a redundant action.

Comment: @user781486 if you've asked hundreds of questions, it's quite handy to mark some of them as favourites.

Comment: @user781486 actually i also recall back when on Anime and Manga we were about to get rid of ID Requests someone finding out that deleted questions marked as favorite still show up in the favorite list (i think if you can view deleted posts)